# JSON String parsing in javascript?

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

I'm using ajax to make a request on a servletand receive json String

servlet code //Server Side

```
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        try { 
        ArrayList<SearchedCourse> searchedCourses = null;
        int semesterNo = request.getParameter("semesterNo");
        searchedCourses = //Using function to retrieve data from DB and return an ArrayList 
        String courses = gson.toJson(searchedCourses);
        out.write(courses);
                }
            }
        }  finally {
            out.close();
        }
    }
```

and this is the return json string "I used firebug to copy it"

```
[{"courseNumber":1619,"courseNo":"HADTA1100","courseName":"قرآن كريم (1) جزء عم","courseExamDate":"Aug 21, 2011","courseExamTimeFrom":"14:30","courseExamTimeTo":"15:30"},{"courseNumber":1663,"courseNo":"HADTB1100","courseName":"قرآن كريم (2) جزء تبارك","courseExamDate":"Aug 23, 2011","courseExamTimeFrom":"14:30","courseExamTimeTo":"15:30"}]
```

I use the code below to parse the Json string 
at the client side

```
  jQuery.ajax({
    url: 'auth/json/AvailableCoursesGetter',
    type: "GET" ,
    dataType: "json",
    data: {
        'semesterNo': 20112
    },
    success: function(data) {
        for (var i = 0, len = data.length; i < len; i++) {
             document.write(data[i].courseNumber);
        }

    }
});
```

it works fine on Mozilla FireFox4, but on Google Chrome and IE it doesn't display any thing

any help ?

Comment: Could be because the courseNumber's aren't in quotes?

Comment: Numbers aren't required to be in quotes in JSON.

Comment: I'm using GSON library to generate this string

Comment: Does your page have a proper UTF encoding declaration?

Comment: yes, and i think that all options are correct

Comment: The JSON validates using http://jsonlint.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just saw that you output the following header in your servlet:

```
response.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/html;charset=UTF-8");
```

Try changing the content type to `application/json`.

Answer (score 3):

@Eli is correct about using the `for in` being a bad idea, but it seems to me that the code should be working.  The following jsFiddle works in IE9 :  http://jsfiddle.net/shaneblake/arhB7/

Are you sure the data is comming back in the correct format and not as a string?  have you tried using `JSON.parse(data)` to make sure?

Comment: You could use ``typeof data`` to see if you get an object or a string.  Also consider outputting the received data to see what you get: ``console.log(data);``

Answer (score 1):

It is considered bad practice to iterate over an array using the `for in` syntax. Try this instead:

```
for (var i = 0, len = data.length; i < len; i++) {
    console.log(data[i].courseNumber);
}
```

If your page in any way has extended the Array prototype, then using `for in` will cause your script to iterate over those extended properties, and if those are being hit before your actual values, it will most likely cause an error. The best way to avoid this is to use a traditional for loop.

Comment: I have no issues running this specific code in my browsers, and I suspect there is something special about your environment that is causing your issue. Could you update your question with any more relevant information that might give clues about the problem?

Comment: Not only is is considered bad practice to iterate over an array using ``for in``, but it actually might *break* your code. ``for in`` does not guarantee the order of the iteration. Element ``n+1`` might be iterated over before element ``n``. This potentially breaks code, so never use ``for in`` to iterate over arrays.